# Validating that an iframe src has a specific url with regex

Tags: regex, iframe, sanitization, markdownsharp

I'm in the middle of integrating MarkdownSharp, a serverside Markdown compilation library.  I have that working, but now I need to sanitize the generated html.

I took a look at the Stack Exchange Data Explorer source code to see how they sanitize their html, and see that they use the following regex to sanitize images post-conversion:

```
private static readonly Regex _whitelist_img =
        new Regex(
            @"
        ^<img\s
        src=""https?://[-a-z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:,.;\(\)]+""
        (\swidth=""\d{1,3}"")?
        (\sheight=""\d{1,3}"")?
        (\salt=""[^""<>]*"")?
        (\stitle=""[^""<>]*"")?
        \s?/?>$",
            RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture | RegexOptions.Compiled |
            RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
```

I've been wrestling with how to do write an analagous regex for whitelist_iframe - that ensures that the iframe contains a link from youtube or vimeo.  The following links are examples of what I'd like to embed:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/IZ_ScEebDOM?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>


<iframe src="//player.vimeo.com/video/80825843?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0" width="500" height="281" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

So I believe the above needs to be modified to:

1. Account for `//` instead of http or https
2. Account for `</iframe>` closing tag
3. Account for `//www.youtube.com` or `//player.vimeo.com` being required in the beginning of the `src` tag.

I'm in the middle of butchering this up as my first regex... any help with this would be much appreciated.

Note that I am not looking to introduce additional libraries or complexity here with a better overall approach, I just want to augement code that's already working, with regex.

Comment: OK... so you don't want to discuss how this might not be a good idea. That's fine. Can you at least show us what you've tried so far? Right now this is just a "gimme the code"-type question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As a beginner in regexes, I can only warn you that this is a slippery slope. Simple constructs are easy to match, but regexes and HTML do not mix well. I *know* that it's been done, but you need to be something of an expert to know when it's a good idea and when it's not. As a self-proclaimed beginner, I suggest you pick up a copy of Friedl's "Mastering Regular Expressions" and read at least the first few chapters before you begin using them. (That's what I did.)

1. **Account for // instead of http or https**

   Remove the "https?:" from the existing regex:

   ```regex
   src=""//[-a-z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:,.;\(\)]+""
   ```
2. **Account for  closing tag**

   Add the closing  tag after the end of your input:

   ```regex
   \s?/?></iframe>$
   ```
3. **Account for //www.youtube.com or //player.vimeo.com being required in the beginning of the src tag.**

   Add the desired domains in a selection list:

   ```regex
   src=""//(www.youtube.com|player.vimeo.com)/[-a-z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:,.;\(\)]+""
   ```